# I got confused with how recursion works in js. Example below

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is a task:

> Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

Example:

Input:

```
[
  [1,3,1],
  [1,5,1],
  [4,2,1]
]
```

Output: `7`

Explanation: Because the path 1→3→1→1→1 minimizes the sum.

And here is my solution, I got confused how stack works. My main question how do I return `minSum` once I found it? As far as I see and what my console.log shows I found the right `minSum`. But how to return a result to main function ?

```
minSum = minSum > curSum ? curSum : minSum;
```

when I change `minSum` in this line does it change minSum in all my other stacks? Is it local variable or it's referenced and no matter where I change it will be changed ? Or should I bother with returns ?

```
var minPathSum = function(grid) {
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    let minSum = 0;
    let curSum = 0;
    
    minSum = 1000000000000; // just to make some minSum to have something to compare with
    findPathSum(grid, j, i, minSum, curSum);
    console.log(minSum, "Main minSum")
    return minSum;
};

function findPathSum(grid, x, y, minSum, curSum){
    if(y + 1 >= grid.length && x + 1 >= grid[0].length)
    { 
        minSum = minSum > curSum ? curSum : minSum;
        console.log(minSum);
        return minSum;
    }
    console.log(grid[y][x], "This is a sum");
    console.log(x, "this is X")
    console.log(y, "This is Y")
    curSum += grid[y][x];
    if (x + 1 < grid[0].length)
        findPathSum(grid, ++x, y, minSum, curSum);
    if(y < grid.length)
        findPathSum(grid, x, ++y, minSum, curSum);
    return minSum;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you do not understand ***your own*** solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the minsum variable to your recursive function, since it is returning a value either way.

```
var minPathSum = function(grid) {
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    let minSum = 1000000000000;
    let curSum = 0;
 
    minsum = findPathSum(grid, j, i, minSum, curSum);
    console.log(minSum, "Main minSum")
    return minSum;
};
```